Is there any matrix ring $R$ such that for all $A\in R$ either $A^3=A$ or $A^3=0$
As we know that in $\mathbb{Z}_4$, each element is either tripotent or their cube is $0$. Same is true for $\mathbb{Z}_8$. I am asking that is this property true only in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ rings or some other rings also? I am trying to consider $2×2$ upper triangular matrix ring over $\mathbb{Z}_4$ or $\mathbb{Z}_8$ to get the benefits of these rings, but it seems like still this property fails to hold as $\begin{pmatrix} 1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}^3=\begin{pmatrix} 1&3\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$. Any hints?

Boolean rings satisfy this

The zero ring satisfies this.

What about
$$
R=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & a & b \cr 0 & 0 & c\cr 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} \mid a,b,c\in K\right\}
$$
for a field (or commutative ring) $K$?

Here $A^3=0$ for all $A$, any other idea where some matrices also satisfy $A^3=A$

For example, $R={ {\rm diag}(a,b,c)\mid a,b,c\in \Bbb F_3}$, because of little Fermat.
